# Why it is possible to pass not higher kinded type?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am reading the book https://underscore.io/books/scala-with-cats/ and trying to understand contravariant in Cats.
On the page 68 there is an example of the implementation of **Contravariant in Cats**

> We can summon instances of `Contravariant` using the `Contravariant.apply` method. Cats provides instances for data types that consume
>   parameters, including `Eq` , `Show` , and `Function1` . Here’s an example:

```
import cats.Contravariant
import cats.Show
import cats.instances.string._

object ContraCats {

  val showString = Show[String]

  val showSymbol = Contravariant[Show]
    .contramap(showString)((sym: Symbol) => s"'${sym.name}'")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(showSymbol.show('dave))
  }

}
```

Show is a typeclass not a type, so how it is possible to create an instance of typeclass `Contravariant` of the typeclass `Show`? And `Show` is not a higher kinded type.

Comment: How is `Show` not a higher kinded type? It's declared as [`Show[T]`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Show.html), it has a type parameter `T`. The question is void.

Comment: Andrey, `Show[T]` has kind `* -> *`.  Is this considered higher kinded, or does the kind need to be `(* -> *) -> *` to be considered higher kinded?

Comment: @earldouglas I've addressed your comment in my answer below. I'd say "yes", it's a higher kind. The thing is: it's essentially irrelevant whether you call `* -> *` or `(* -> *) -> *` "higher kinded", because if there is no `(* -> *) -> *`, then thingies of kind `* -> *` do not make any sense, because there is nothing that could consume them and give back something concrete of simple kind `*`. What is important is that "the language has support for higher kinds": this automatically implies that there must be ways to construct `* -> *` and thingies of kind `(* -> *) -> *` which can consume them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typeclass `Show` is declared as [`Show[T]`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/Show.scala).

`Contravariant` is declared as [`Contravariant[F[_]]`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/Contravariant.scala)

If we say that

- `Int` has kind `*`
- `List[Int]` has kind `*`
- `List` has kind `* -> *`
- `Monad` declared as `trait Monad[M[_]]` has kind `(* -> *) -> *`

then by analogy:

- `Show` has kind `* -> *`
- `Show[Int]` has kind `*`
- `Contravariant` has kind `(* -> *) -> *`
- `Contravariant[Show]` has kind `*`

That is, `Contravariant` is a thing that takes `* -> *` and produces something of kind `*`. Since `Show` is of kind `* -> *`, the type `Contravariant[Show]` is valid.

Now, in your code snippet, there is an *expression* `Contravariant[Show]`. It's not a type, and it should not be confused with the application of a type constructor. Desugared, this thing is essentially

```
Contravariant.apply[Show](inst)
```

where `Contravariant` is the [companion object of trait `Contravariant`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Contravariant$.html) and `inst` is an implicitly supplied instance of *type* `Contravariant[Show]`. Again, everything fits together seamlessly.

**Remark on nomenclature.** I would say that `Show` is a "higher kind". It's in no way definitive, but I like the following quote from the [Atlassian Blog](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/archives/scala-types-of-a-higher-kind) [emphasis and code indentation mine]:

> Furthermore, you can have kinds that are themselves **parameterized by higher kinded** types. So, something could not only take a type, but take something that itself takes type parameters. An example would be the covariant functor: Functor[F[_]], it has the kind:

```
((* -> *) -> *)
```

> This says: given a **simple higher kinded type**, produce the final type. For instance given a **type constructor like List** produce the final type Functor[List].

From the above quote it is evident that it is at least *common* to refer to the kind `* -> *` of `List` as "higher kind". It's definitely higher than `*`. It's definitely higher than anything you can write down in current version of Java (if you write `List` in Java, the best you can get is a "blah blah the generic type List requires type parameters blah blah"-error).

Comment: @zero_coding: There is a trait `Show`, declared as `trait Show[T]`. The type constructor `Show` has kind `* -> *`. Then there is a companion object, also called `Show`, which appears in your code as `val showString = Show.apply[String]`. Since there are implicit instances of `Show`, it can be *considered a typeclass*. There is no keyword / runtime data structure "typeclass" in Scala, it's not Haskell. A "typeclass" is just a type constructor and some implicitly provided instances of it.

Comment: What does it mean `trait Show[T]` extends `Show.ContravariantShow[T]`? On `Show.ContravariantShow[T]` there is a function `def show(t: T): String`, what do I have with it on `trait Show[T]`?

Comment: It means that `trait Show[T]` extends the trait `ContravariantShow[T]`, which is declared in the companion object `Show`. `Show[T]` is essentially the same thing as `ContravariantShow[-T]`, but with variance erased. It has exactly the same method `def show(t: T): String` as `ContravariantShow[-T]`, but `Show[T]` is declared invariant in the type parameter `T`, that's the whole difference.

Comment: @zero_coding: Just look at the source code of [Show.scala](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/Show.scala), both `Show` and `ContravariantShow[-T]` are there, it's all in the first 20 lines. Just completely usual trait inheritance. No type-level computations, no implicit-magic, no macros, nothing fancy at all. Good old `extends`, the same as in Java, just a little more refined because of declaration-site variance annotations.